# Rewrite Code to be Efficient (Button Increment Text view)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I have 5 editTexts and 2 buttons for each editText so 10 of them. Each one is supposed to increment/decrement a specific editText. Now my code works entirely but as you'll soon see, it is not efficient and doesn't even make sure the numbers are between 0-59 (clock that can be set for n minutes) for the editTexts that are supposed to contain minutes. Anyhow I just want to know the best or most-efficient way to properly do this.

My idea was to have a separate method that takes in parameters such as the specific editText to increment/decrement and another param for whether to add or subtract but I am not sure for the implementation since OnClickListener() has to have the public void onClick(View v) method.

Thanks!

Code:

```
package com.clock;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class addCourse extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addcourse);

    final Button save_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSave);
    final Button cancel_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCancel);
    final Button higherNumber_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.higherNumber_Button);
    final Button lowerNumber_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lowerNumber_Button);
    final Button higherClasshh_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.higherClasshh_Button);
    final Button lowerClasshh_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lowerClasshh_Button);
    final Button higherClassmm_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.higherClassmm_Button);
    final Button lowerClassmm_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lowerClassmm_Button);
    final Button higherClockhh_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.higherClockhh_Button);
    final Button lowerClockhh_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lowerClockhh_Button);
    final Button higherClockmm_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.higherClockmm_Button);
    final Button lowerClockmm_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lowerClockmm_Button);
    final EditText courseCredits_Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseCredits_Edit);
    final EditText hhClass_Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.classHours_Edit);
    final EditText mmClass_Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.classMins_Edit);
    final EditText hhClock_Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clockHours_Edit);
    final EditText mmClock_Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clockMins_Edit);

    higherNumber_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(courseCredits_Edit.getText().toString());
            ++a;
            courseCredits_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    lowerNumber_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(courseCredits_Edit.getText().toString());
            --a;
            courseCredits_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    higherClasshh_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(hhClass_Edit.getText().toString());
            ++a;
            hhClass_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    lowerClasshh_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(hhClass_Edit.getText().toString());
            --a;
            hhClass_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    higherClassmm_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(mmClass_Edit.getText().toString());
            ++a;
            mmClass_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    lowerClassmm_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(mmClass_Edit.getText().toString());
            --a;
            mmClass_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    higherClockhh_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(hhClock_Edit.getText().toString());
            ++a;
            hhClock_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    lowerClockhh_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(hhClock_Edit.getText().toString());
            --a;
            hhClock_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    higherClockmm_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(mmClock_Edit.getText().toString());
            ++a;
            mmClock_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    lowerClockmm_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            int a = Integer.parseInt(mmClock_Edit.getText().toString());
            --a;
            mmClock_Edit.setText(a + "");
        }
    });

    save_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks

        }
    });

    cancel_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}`

Comment: Ugh why not have the Activity implement OnClickListener?  Then in the onClick method using a switch statement along with a tag id to either a-- or a++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) use the "tag" property of each one of your button in your xml layout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

> Tags
>
> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially
>   an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They
>   are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in
>   the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate
>   structure.

2) use also onclick in your xml

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:tag="1"
     android:onClick="doSomething" />
```

in your code:

```
public void doSomething(View v){
    int tag=v.getTag();
    //Do something smart with button, like odd numbers = plus and even = minus.
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()

If you want to programmaticaly, with the code above, get the corresponding edittext, just store their ID in an arraylist and play with the int to get the corresponding EditText.